# How to elimnate the effect of upper- and lower case in database filter - vue - laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, filtering, uppercase, lowercase

I have written a filter function that filters by column. I noticed, that when a word is uppercase, it won't give the result if the word is in lowercase.

**For example:** I search the term `Paper`,  I get all of the rows that contain the word `Paper` but I don't get the rows who contain `paper`.

I could say when I paste a word to filter, automatically make it lowercase but then I want to get the rows containing `Paper`. How can I resolve this?

How can I ignore the lower and uppercase in my filter? 
Thanks for the help.

## html Part

```
<b-table class="col-sm-12 table-sm" show-empty striped hover stacked="md" tbody-tr-class="addPointer"
    :items="filter"
    :fields="fields"
    @filter="onFilter">

    <template slot="top-row" >
        <td v-for="field in Object.keys(fields)" :key="field.key">
            <input class="col-sm" v-if="Object.keys(filters).indexOf(field) !== -1" v-model="filters[field]" :placeholder="field">
        </td>
    </template>
    <template slot="name" slot-scope="row">
        {{row.item.name}}
    </template>
</b-table>
```

## Function

```
data() {
   return {

        filters: {
                name:'',
        },
       }
     },
     computed:{ 
        filter () {
            const filter = this.datas.filter(value => {
                    String(value[key]).includes(this.filters[key]))
            })
            return filter.length > 0 ? filter : [
                {
                    name:'',
                }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `toLowerCase()` on results from database and your input.

In your case:

```
const filter = this.datas.filter(value => {
                    String(value[key].toLowerCase()).includes(this.filters[key].toLowerCase()))
            })
```